# How to disable button till finish a function and be enable again using python and html.Button

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have just tried to create a `loading` component as to make the button disabled but I couldn't manage to make it `disabled` during the process in `input_triggers_spinner` called `my_DB_func()`. The below code just creates the loading till this function is finished, but I want to disable this `button` till the process finish.

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import time
from Missing_relation_All import my_DB_func

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Button('Create Missing Relation Script', id='input-1', disabled=False),
        dcc.Loading(id="loading-1", children=[html.Div(id="loading-output-1")], type="default"),
    ],
)

@app.callback(Output("loading-output-1", "children"), [Input("input-1", "n_clicks")])
def input_triggers_spinner(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks == True:
        my_DB_func()
        return 'Script have been created successful :) !!!!'


    elif n_clicks != True:
        return 'Please Click Here'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838853/disable-submit-button-for-30-seconds-in-python-dash
 All I'd expect you'd need, is to set the button disabled right before calling your DB_func, and then set it as active after the DB_func finishes or throws an error.

Comment: @HammerN'Songs I am sorry...
Could you explain more related to my code?

Comment: Have you tried to put your button in Loading component?